# Detecting objects and then computing pose of object/camera in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, pose-estimation

Assuming there are two cameras in 3D space, spaced apart, looking at the same scene. I am trying to achieve the following through opencv: (please correct me if my approach is wrong)

1. Camera1 which is fixed, looks at an object, computes pose of the object through solvePnP.
2. Camera2's position is noisy, so there's noise in terms of both rotation and translation. It looks at the same object, and computes the pose at every frame.
3. Frame-by-frame, I would then solve for the pose of the moving camera and use that info for stabilizing it.

Is it possible to do this by detecting a generic planar object in the scene (not a checkerboard), and using it for pose estimation? Any pointers or suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Sai

Comment: detecting general objects remains something too hard for computers today. however, visual SLAM, which tracks feature points and estimate camera pose in the real world show up great. I think this would help you. google visual SLAM and PTAM.

Comment: Hi, correct me if I am wrong, but don't SLAM techniques need somewhat of a consistent, constant motion from the camera's end for reliable pose estimation? In my application, there is one camera just exhibiting some noise. What I was thinking of was some kind of corner/feature detection of one particular object in the scene, but I am still not sure of how to tell the algorithm to only 'lock on' to that particular target, and then estimate its pose..

Comment: SLAM means to solve the problem of knowing relation between the camera and the environment simultaneous. rather than some particular object, trying to build the whole map of the environment would be much more fancy! and the feature of one particular object would be noisy, different view, motion blur...  check PTAM demo, that's would give you something.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether the object is a checkerboard or not, you need a way to reliably map 3d points (on the object), to 2d ones (on the images).

With the setup you describe, you can get the pose of the moving camera w.r.t the fixed one object as object-to-fixed * inverse(object-to-moving). This will work even if the object is w.r.t either camera, provided that the cameras are synchronized.

Comment: Hi Francesco, thanks for the reply. I have a high level understanding of what you mean by 3d->2d projection, do you have any tips about what algorithms I would have to look at from an opencv perspective? I am still somewhat of a beginner in OpenCV and computer vision concepts. Can I somehow find the corners of the most dominant planar object in the scene and then estimate its size and go from there..?

Comment: Start from here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html. Assuming you have calibrated the cameras already (i.e. the intrinsic parameters are known), you can use solvePnP to solve for the pose. For that you need 3d->2d correspondences. This means identifying in the images points belonging to the scene object at known spatial locations w.r.t. each other. A checkerboard helps obtaining precise correspondences. It is not required, any object (a.k.a. "rig") that helps finding correspondences will do.